# Not solved to optimality Error, using Ipopt

Tags: optimization, julia, nonlinear-optimization

Trying to run the below, which is to solve a constrained NL system of equations:

```
using JuMP
using Ipopt
m=Model(solver=IpoptSolver())
@variable(m,k,start=0.1)
@variable(m,c,start=1.2)
@variable(m,l,start=0.3)
@NLparameter(m,α==0.21)
@NLparameter(m,β==0.99)
@NLparameter(m,γ==0.4)
@NLparameter(m,μ==0.2)
@NLparameter(m,δ==0.14)
@NLparameter(m,θ==0.25)
@NLconstraint(m,c-c*β*(1-δ+((α/μ)*(k^(α-1))*l^(1-α)))==0)
@NLconstraint(m,θ*c*l^(1/γ)-((1-α)/μ)*k^α*l^-α ==0)
@NLconstraint(m,c+δ*k-k^α*l^(1-α)==0)
@NLconstraint(m,l==0.33)
@NLconstraint(m,(1-δ+((α/μ)*(k^(α-1))*l^(1-α)))-(1.05)^(1/4)==0)
@NLobjective(m,Max,1.0)
solve(m)
println("k=", getvalue(k),"c=", getvalue(c),"l=", getvalue(l))
status=solve(m)
```

But, I am receiving the below error message:

WARNING: Ipopt finished with status Not_Enough_Degrees_Of_Freedom
WARNING: Not solved to optimality, status: Error
WARNING: Ipopt finished with status Not_Enough_Degrees_Of_Freedom
WARNING: Not solved to optimality, status: Error

This is the equilibrium condition of an economic model, with 2 constraints (Const. 4 and 5) 
Please, is there anything wrong with the code? Or is there another way (a different solver, package, ..)for solving this constrained problem.

Comment: `@variable(m,l,start=0.3)` and `@NLconstraint(m,l==0.33)` are both in the model. If `l` is going to be `0.33`, why optimize over it? In any case, there are 5 constraints with 3 variables - the warning might be saying something right

Comment: Removing @variable(m,l,start=0.3) and setting l==0.33 as a parameter does not solve the issue. Just more info: The first 3 constraints constitute my core system of 3 NL equations in (k,c,l) that I want to solve. But, I want to constraint l=0.33 and also a part of the first equation of the system (1-δ+((α/μ)*(k^(α-1))*l^(1-α))) to be =(1.05)  ^(1/4). Would there be another way to get around?

Comment: There are still 4 constraints and 2 variables. Perhaps there is no solution (think: 4 lines in a plane do not have to have a point on all of them). In any case, you could add *slack variables* on a constraint (or two) and then try to minimize the slack variables (i.e. minimize the sum of their absolute values or sum of squares).

Comment: Indeed,as it is designed now, it is infeasible as problem. Even introducing two slack variables in a constraint and then having 5 constraints and 5 variables doesn't. I am going to re-design the problem, may be dropping off some parameters and considering them as variables.

Comment: It works. I considered θ and β as variables and moreover, their returned values are quite close to their "priors" as parameters. Thanks

Comment: well, consider writing a little answer for yourself just to have this question covered ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to solve a system of NL equations that has more constraints (equations) than variables (unknowns). Moreover, equation (5) is a constraint imposed on a part of equation (1) on a theoretical (economics) basis. It comes then that there is not a feasible solution for (c, l, k) satisfying the 5 constraints (Not enough degree of freedom). Considering two of the parameters of the model (θ and β) as variables, leads to a feasible problem with an optimal solution found.